# Saving a JSON object as the entire model in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to save the information that my front sends me in the database (I receive a JSON), the problem is that there are foreign keys in the model and these may or may not be filled and when I try to save some data with the empty FK I receive the 'matching' error query does not exist.' or other errors related to the 'key' not existing in the database. What occurs to me is to remove it from the front before it is sent to DJANGO and save the object as such but I don't know if it's possible, if you also have another solution I would greatly appreciate it

Add

```py
def agregarIniciativa(request):

  if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method =='POST':
            try:
                data = json.load(request)
                iniciativa = Iniciativa(
                    iniciativa = data['nombre'],
                    fecha_inicio = data['fecha_inicio'],
                    fecha_final = data['fecha_final'],
                    canal=Canales.objects.get(id=int(data['canal'])),
                    territorio = data['territorios'],
                    audiencia = AudienciaDirigida.objects.get(id=int(data['audiencia'])),
                    bigbet = BigBet.objects.get(id=int(data['bigBet'])),
                    marca = Marcas.objects.get(id=int(data['marca'])),
                    fgp = float(data['fgp']),
                    objetivo = data['objetivo'],
                    call2action = data['call2Action'],
                    dialogo_valor = data['dialogoValor'],
                    cobertura = data['cobertura'],
                    volumen_datos = data['volumen'],
                    kpi_medicion = data['kpi'],
                    inversion_datos = data['inversion'],
                    beneficio_datos = data['beneficio'],
                    volumen_total = int(data['total_vol']),
                    inversion_total = int(data['total_inv']),
                    beneficio_total = int(data['total_ben']),
                    marcas = data['marcas'],
                    fgp_datos = data['fgpDatos']
                )
                iniciativa.save()
                return JsonResponse({
                    "msg": "Guardado"
                })

            except Exception as e:
                 print('Error: Agregar iniciativa')
                 print(str(e))
                 return HttpResponseBadRequest('Error al agregar iniciativa.', format(request.method), status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Favor de ingresar sesión en el sistema.', format(request.method), status=401)
```

Model.py

```py
class Iniciativa(models.Model):
    iniciativa      = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    fecha_inicio    = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_final     = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    canal           = models.ForeignKey(Canales, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    territorio      = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True)
    audiencia       = models.ForeignKey(AudienciaDirigida, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bigbet          = models.ForeignKey(BigBet, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marca           = models.ForeignKey(Marcas, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fgp             = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    objetivo        = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    call2action     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    dialogo_valor   = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cobertura       = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    kpi_medicion    = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    volumen_datos   = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True)

    inversion_datos = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True) 

    beneficio_datos = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True)

    avance_captura = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    observaciones  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    observaciones_solventadas  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    aprobada       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ranking        = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ranking_temp   = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    volumen_total   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=15, default=0.0, null=True)
    inversion_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=15, default=0.0, null=True)
    beneficio_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=15, default=0.0, null=True)
    fgp_datos       = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True)
    marcas          = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True) 
    estatus         = models.IntegerField(choices=ESTATUS,default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Iniciativa'
        verbose_name_plural='Iniciativas'
        ordering=('id',)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.iniciativa
```